# How to make number picker with only available numbers?

Tags: android, sqlite

My app is using api 7. I don't know where to start with this challenge.

I have SQLite DB with some numbers stored between 1-99. Now I would like to make number picker for this range which would also remove numbers that are already in DB.

Comment: What are you having issues with? the picker itself, retrieving the existing numbers from the db, something else? Also, what have you tried already?

Comment: I'm fairly beginner with Android and I'm looking where to begin. Is there any widget to use? I noticed that number picker widget is usable only since api 11.

Comment: Your first consideration is what phones/versions you want to target. Assuming you want to go api >= 11, have a look at [this article](http://shanetully.com/2011/12/android-3-x-and-4-x-numberpicker-example/) for details on the number picker. I'd suggest you might get a better response on SO if you make your question more specific - eg `How to display an arbitrary list of numbers in a number picker`, `How to retrieve the contents of a column from the database`, etc... With a more specific Q, you're more likely to get useful answers and code examples. Good luck and welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a list off the numbers 0-99, then do a query on your database. For every row in the results from the database, check if the list contains is (something like list.contains(number). If it is there, remove it (list.remove(item)) then proceed to the next row

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to make your own widget. This will be somewhat involved, and since you are an Android beginner you might better spend your time coming up with a different input method.

In case you do decide to write your own widget, I would recommend extending LinearLayout, then inside of the constructor, doing something like this psuedocode:

```
setOrientation(VERTICAL);
addView ImageButton arrowUpButton;
addView EditText numberEditText;
addView ImageButton arrowDownButton;

arrowUpButton.setOnClickListener {
     int num = myListOfInts.get(currentIndex++);

     numberEditText.setText(num);

}

//vice versa for arrowDownButton
```

you'd also have to create a setter for the myListOfInts.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I will try building widget tomorrow and see if I get it to work.

Comment: @Gioberti Did you ever end up doing this?

Comment: Sorry, I've been little busy... I'll post how it went once I get back to my project. Probably next week.

Comment: Decided to go with list view instead of creating own widget.